# Change onclick action to an automatic action

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following JavaScript code:

```
onclick = function(){ infocontainer.appendChild(info); }
```

But that works only when I click somewhere else on my page. How can I change the onclick action to an automatic action without the need to click?

Comment: Do you want the function to run on page load?

Comment: just click it programmatically (the laziest solution)

Comment: Yes, i want to run on page load

Comment: @RollzRoyce please take a look at me answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your explanation

You can use this:

```
window.onload = function() {
  yourFunction(param1, param2);
};
```

This will load `yourFunction` when the page is done loading

Answer (score 1):

You can replace your `onclick` function with self-invoking anonymous function:

```
(function(){ infocontainer.appendChild(info); })();
```

It will be called immediately on script load.

Either use a function declaration and simply call it:

```
function set(){ infocontainer.appendChild(info); }
set();
```

Or use `window.onload` function, which will execute given action on window load.

```
window.onload = function(){
   infocontainer.appendChild(info);
}
```

Comment: self-invoking anonymous function is absolutely unnecessary here.

Comment: @dfsq Feel free to post an alternative solution in your answer.

Comment: I'm not saying it's not right, it's it's the same as just `infocontainer.appendChild(info);`.

Comment: @dfsq I just assumed that OP prefers to use it as a function.